# ModuleNotFoundError in import sql.connector in VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, mysql-connector

I am doing same thing in ipython, it is working there but in VScode it shows:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package
All other package I install work fine but having trouble only with this. I have installed using pip. Any solution for this?

Python 3.9.0
pip 21.0.1
Regards,

python

Comment: How did you install this module? Please check whether the module installation location is in the python environment currently used by VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

For installing and checking Python modules in VS Code, please refer to the following:

1. Please make sure that the python environment used by the current VS Code terminal is the same as that shown in the lower left corner of VS Code. (`python --version` or `pip --version`)
2. Install the module "[mysql-connector](https://pypi.org/project/mysql-connector/)".(`pip install mysql-connector`)
3. Check the module. (`pip show mysql-connector`)

   [image]

Run:

[image]

If it still doesn't work, please try to uninstall this module and reinstall it.

Reference: [Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).

Comment: @Regina -That's great! If my answer solves the problem, please [mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as an answer to help others find this solution.

Comment: I try but I see this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: @Regina -Please try to refresh this page and put a green flag next to my answer. like this:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work  thanks a lot!